# Drivers for the Netgear wifi adapter A6100

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.04, netgear

I have recently switched to Ubuntu, and I have no other way of accessing the internet on my computer because my router doesn't support ethernet, so I have a wifi adapter, and I've seen a bunch of different tutorials but they all require an internet connection first to install make or dkms.

Comment: Do you have a friend or neighbor that might let you borrow an ethernet connection? Can't you tether your phone? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The driver you compiled doesn't cover your device at all. You can confirm it with:

modinfo 8812au | grep 9052

Where '9052' is the last part of your usb.id:

```
ID 0846:9052 NetGear, Inc. A6100 AC600 DB Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8811AU]
```

The command will come back blank.

Let's remove it. In the terminal, navigate to the location of the file you downloaded, for an example, Downloads:

cd ~/Downloads/rtl8812AU
sudo make uninstall
cd ..
rm -rf rtl8812AU

Now let's download a better file:

sudo apt update
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux.git
cd rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux
make
sudo make install

Check:

modinfo rtl8812au.ko | grep 9052

The terminal should return your device ID:

alias:          usb:v0846p9052d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*

Reboot and you should be all set.

Comment: How do you know OP has that device and installed that driver?? Does that "better file" build successfully on OP's kernel version? Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

As most of the driver installation guides I found didn't work on Kali Linux due to some errors while using make, I had to troubleshoot for hours to finally find a tutorial that worked. This should also work for Ubuntu/Lubuntu etc. in case you have the same difficulties using the files from a github link mentioned on the other comments.
https://kalitut.com/how-to-install-rtl8812au/

I also created an executable bash file to automatically install the drivers for your system, which can be found on my GitHub:
https://github.com/Kiikuri/netgear_a6100_ac600_driver_installer_linux
Just download the file or input the contents into a text/bash file, and run:
bash NETGEAR_A6100_driver_installer.sh
or
bash <insert_name>.txt/sh